# MediaPlayer no se reproduce en CountDownTimer

Tags: android, mediaplayer, countdowntimer

Tengo un `CountDownTimer` de la siguiente manera:

```
cuentaAtras = new CountDownTimer(mili, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;


                if (seconds  <= TIEMPO3){

                    if (tic1.isPlaying()){
                        tic1.stop();
                        tic2.start();
                    }

                } else if (seconds <= TIEMPO && seconds > TIEMPO2 + 10){
                    tic1.start();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                if (tic2.isPlaying())
                {
                    tic2.stop();
                }
                ticExp.start();

                tic1.reset();
                tic2.reset();
                ticExp.reset();

            }
        }.start();
```

Las variables `tic1`, `tic2` y `ticExp` son de tipo **`MediaPlayer`** y los inicializo de la siguiente manera:

```
 tic1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tic1);
 tic1.setLooping(true);
 tic2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tic3);
 tic2.setLooping(true);
 ticExp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.exp);
```

El problema viene cuando se ejecuta el método `onFinish`, ya que debería reproducirse el `ticExp` pero eso no ocurre nunca.

He probado metiéndolo en el método *`onTick`*, y si que se reproduce, por lo que está descartadísimo que el archivo de audio esté corrompido o algo.
No tengo ni idea de porque en el *`onTick`* se reproduce y en el *`onFinish`* nunca llega a escucharse. (Pero si llega a ejecutarse las demás instrucciones, como por ejemplo que `tic2` deje de escucharse)

Espero escuchar vuestras sugerencias para solucionar un problema que me está dando dolores de cabeza. Gracias.

Comment: Cual es el comportamiento que deseas?

Comment: @Jorgesys Que cuando el `CountDownTimer` finalice, es decir, se ejecute el `onFinish`, se reproduzca el `ticExp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es que ejecutaba el `ticExp.reset()` después del `ticExp.start()` y no le daba tiempo a ejecutarse y lo reseteaba.
Quité la línea de `ticExp.reset()` y ya funciona.

Respuesta que recibí en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834003/8504719).